# Point-Open Topology is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and equip $C(X,Y)$ with the [point-open topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411045/topology-of-pointwise-convergence-and-point-open-topology-are-equivalent) (generalized the topology of pointwise convergence) generated by the following sub-base:
$$
V(x,U)\triangleq \left\{
f\in C(X,Y):\,
f(x)\subseteq U
\right\},
$$
where $x \in X$ and $U$ is open in $Y$.  If $Y$ is Hausdorff and $X$ is $T_1$, then is the point-open topology Hausdorff also?

Comment: The point-open topology agrees with the topology of pointwise convergence. You do not need $X$ to be $T_1$ to show that If $Y$, then the point-open topology is Hausdorff.

Comment: @PaulFrost interesting; I just happened to notice the same thing in a comment below.  This is a nice coincidence :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \neq g$ then there exist $x$ such that $f(x) \neq g(x)$. There exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $W$ containing $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively. Now $V(x,U)$ and $V(x,W)$ are disjoint open sets containing $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thanks you Kabo; so the proof is the same as in the Compact-open topology then.

Comment: @AIM_BLB that topology is finer, so also Hausdorff. You use singletons in the compact- open case.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think it is only finer if $X$ is also Hausdorff, since for example if $X$ is equipped with a topology which is not $T_1$ then no singelton $\{x\}$ for $x \in X$ is closed (and therefore is not compact).

Comment: @AIM_BLB no, it’s always finer as finite sets are compact in any space.

Comment: Ah, you're right; very silly of me.